# Unmarshal JSON with some known, and some unknown field names

Tags: json, go

I have the following JSON

```
{"a":1, "b":2, "?":1, "??":1}
```

I know that it has the "a" and "b" fields, but I don't know the names of other fields. So I want to unmarshal it in the following type:

```
type Foo struct {
  // Known fields
  A int `json:"a"`
  B int `json:"b"`
  // Unknown fields
  X map[string]interface{} `json:???` // Rest of the fields should go here.
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 72):

### Unmarshal twice

One option is to unmarshal twice: once into a value of type `Foo` and once into a value of type `map[string]interface{}` and removing the keys `"a"` and `"b"`:

```
type Foo struct {
    A int                    `json:"a"`
    B int                    `json:"b"`
    X map[string]interface{} `json:"-"` // Rest of the fields should go here.
}

func main() {
    s := `{"a":1, "b":2, "x":1, "y":1}`
    f := Foo{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f.X); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    delete(f.X, "a")
    delete(f.X, "b")

    fmt.Printf("%+v", f)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MbGVDwBgzy)):

```
{A:1 B:2 X:map[x:1 y:1]}
```

### Unmarshal once and manual handling

Another option is to unmarshal once into an `map[string]interface{}` and handle the `Foo.A` and `Foo.B` fields manually:

```
type Foo struct {
    A int                    `json:"a"`
    B int                    `json:"b"`
    X map[string]interface{} `json:"-"` // Rest of the fields should go here.
}

func main() {
    s := `{"a":1, "b":2, "x":1, "y":1}`
    f := Foo{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f.X); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if n, ok := f.X["a"].(float64); ok {
        f.A = int(n)
    }
    if n, ok := f.X["b"].(float64); ok {
        f.B = int(n)
    }
    delete(f.X, "a")
    delete(f.X, "b")

    fmt.Printf("%+v", f)
}
```

Output is the same ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/juAjK6ymIk)):

```
{A:1 B:2 X:map[x:1 y:1]}
```

Comment: Anyway to automate the handling of A and B? When handling structs with ~20 instead of 2 fields this will lead to really lengthy code.

Answer (score 28):

It's not nice, but you could to it by implementing `Unmarshaler`:

```
type _Foo Foo

func (f *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) (err error) {
    foo := _Foo{}

    if err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &foo); err == nil {
        *f = Foo(foo)
    }

    m := make(map[string]interface{})

    if err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &m); err == nil {
        delete(m, "a")
        delete(m, "b")
        f.X = m
    }

    return err
}
```

The type `_Foo` is necessary to avoid recursion while decoding.

Comment: Why would using just Foo cause recursion?

Comment: btw I used this with some good success. example here: https://play.golang.org/p/WLeEJIESg6

Comment: I also think this solution of leveraging the bson module is nice, especially if you already include it as a dependency: http://devel.io/2013/08/19/go-handling-arbitrary-json/

Comment: "Why would using just Foo cause recursion?" - @Chris 
The json package checks if a type has `UnmarshalJSON()` defined, and if so it calls that implementation. So we arrive at the top of the function, then we call `Unmarshal()` on `f`, and the json package checks if `Foo` has `UnmarshalJSON()` defined, and it does, so it calls it, and so on, to infinite recursion.  The purpose of `_Foo` is to be a type that does _not_ implement `UnmarshalJSON()`, to break the cycle.

Comment: Chris' Link to devel.io is dead by now. To save you the search on the wayback machine, it can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20161019055501/http://devel.io/2013/08/19/go-handling-arbitrary-json/

Comment: There is a proposal to add an 'inline' struct tag into golang core https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6213

Answer (score 22):

Simplest way is to use an interface like this:

```
var f interface{}
s := `{"a":1, "b":2, "x":1, "y":1}`

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

[Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/HV5bYV4uud)

Comment: It unmarshals this way, but how do you access the values after that?

Comment: You have to use type switches to access the values. Possible types will be `string`, `int`, `map[string]interface{}`, `nil`, `bool`, and so forth.

Comment: Could you provide a small example? I'm looking for information on how to do it and I can't find the way, thanks

Comment: How to access the elements:  https://go.dev/play/p/FkOE_X2dmqt

Comment: How is this different from unmarshalling into a `map[string]interface{}`?

Comment: It's different to `map[string]interface{}` as `interface{}` will handle any structure or type like an int array `[1, 2, 3]` for example.

Answer (score 20):

I use interface to unmarshal uncertain type json.

```
bytes := []byte(`{"name":"Liam","gender":1, "salary": 1}`)
var p2 interface{}
json.Unmarshal(bytes, &p2)
m := p2.(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(m)
```

Answer (score 18):

## Almost single pass, uses `json.RawMessage`

We can unmarshal into `map[string]json.RawMessage`, and then unmarshal each field separately.

JSON will be tokenized twice, but that's quite cheap.

The following helper function can be used:

```
func UnmarshalJsonObject(jsonStr []byte, obj interface{}, otherFields map[string]json.RawMessage) (err error) {
    objValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    knownFields := map[string]reflect.Value{}
    for i := 0; i != objValue.NumField(); i++ {
        jsonName := strings.Split(objValue.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("json"), ",")[0]
        knownFields[jsonName] = objValue.Field(i)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &otherFields)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for key, chunk := range otherFields {
        if field, found := knownFields[key]; found {
            err = json.Unmarshal(chunk, field.Addr().Interface())
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            delete(otherFields, key)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Here is the complete code on Go Playground - http://play.golang.org/p/EtkJUzMmKt

Comment: This only works with objects, not arrays, nor strings, all of which are valid json

Answer (score 9):

### Single Pass With Marshmallow

We use [marshmallow](https://github.com/PerimeterX/marshmallow) to solve exactly that problem. It requires no explicit coding of any kind which keeps your code cleaner and more maintainable than other solutions, but it also provides the best performance (up to x3 faster than other solutions provided here, see benchmarks and results [in the repo](https://github.com/PerimeterX/marshmallow#performance-benchmark-and-alternatives)).

```golang
type Foo struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
    B int `json:"b"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"a":1, "b":2, "x":1, "y":1}`
    f := Foo{}
    result, err := marshmallow.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f)      // {A:1 B:2}
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result) // map[a:1 b:2 x:1 y:1]
}
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/0NzXwSuR6lJ)

Marshmallow is used internally at PerimeterX for some time and we've recently decided to open-source it. We also wrote a [blog post](https://www.perimeterx.com/tech-blog/2022/boosting-up-json-performance-of-unstructured-structs-in-go/) about how it helped us trim 70% of our JSON parsing costs in production.

Answer (score 6):

## Single pass, use `github.com/ugorji/go/codec`

When unmarshaling into a `map`, `encoding/json` empties the map, but `ugorji/go/codec` doesn't. It also attempts to fill existing values, so we can put pointers to foo.A, foo.B into foo.X:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ugorji/go/codec"
)

type Foo struct {
    A int
    B int
    X map[string]interface{}
}

func (this *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(jsonStr []byte) (err error) {
    this.X = make(map[string]interface{})
    this.X["a"] = &this.A
    this.X["b"] = &this.B
    return codec.NewDecoderBytes(jsonStr, &codec.JsonHandle{}).Decode(&this.X)
}

func main() {
    s := `{"a":1, "b":2, "x":3, "y":[]}`
    f := &Foo{}
    err := codec.NewDecoderBytes([]byte(s), &codec.JsonHandle{}).Decode(f)
    fmt.Printf("err = %v\n", err)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Hashicorp's map-to-struct decoder, which keeps track of unused fields: https://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#example-Decode--Metadata

It's two-pass, but you don't have to use known field names anywhere.

```
func UnmarshalJson(input []byte, result interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    // unmarshal json to a map
    foomap := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal(input, &foomap)

    // create a mapstructure decoder
    var md mapstructure.Metadata
    decoder, err := mapstructure.NewDecoder(
        &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
            Metadata: &md,
            Result:   result,
        })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // decode the unmarshalled map into the given struct
    if err := decoder.Decode(foomap); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // copy and return unused fields
    unused := map[string]interface{}{}
    for _, k := range md.Unused {
        unused[k] = foomap[k]
    }
    return unused, nil
}

type Foo struct {
    // Known fields
    A int
    B int
    // Unknown fields
    X map[string]interface{} // Rest of the fields should go here.
}

func main() {
    s := []byte(`{"a":1, "b":2, "?":3, "??":4}`)

    var foo Foo
    unused, err := UnmarshalJson(s, &foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    foo.X = unused
    fmt.Println(foo) // prints {1 2 map[?:3 ??:4]}
}
```