# Is there a way to have json.Unmarshal() select struct type based on "type" property?

Tags: json, go, interface

I have some JSON of the form:

```
[{
    "type": "car",
    "color": "red",
    "hp": 85,
    "doors": 4
}, {
    "type": "plane",
    "color": "blue",
    "engines": 3
}]
```

I have types `car` and `plane` that satisfy a vehicle interface; I'd like to be able to write:

```
var v []vehicle
e := json.Unmarshal(myJSON, &v)
```

... and have JSON fill my slice of vehicles with a car and a plane; instead (and unsurprisingly) I just get "cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.vehicle".

For reference, here are suitable definitions of the types involved:

```
type vehicle interface {
    vehicle()
}

type car struct {
    Type  string
    Color string
    HP    int
    Doors int
}

func (car) vehicle() { return }

type plane struct {
    Type    string
    Color   string
    Engines int
}

func (plane) vehicle() { return }

var _ vehicle = (*car)(nil)
var _ vehicle = (*plane)(nil)
```

(Note that I'm actually totally uninterested in the `t` field on `car` and `plane` - it could be omitted because this information will, if someone successfully answers this question, be implicit in the dynamic type of the objects in `v`.)

Is there a way to have the JSON umarhsaller choose which type to use based on some part of the contents (in this case, the type field) of the data being decoded?

(Note that this is **not** a duplicate of [Unmarshal JSON with unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-unknown-fields) because I want each item in the slice to have a different dynamic type, and from the value of the 'type' property I know *exactly* what fields to expect—I just don't know how to tell json.Unmarshal how to map 'type' property values onto Go types.)

Comment: Yes, you can implement `json.Unamrshaler`, but it depends on what you want your final data structure to look like. What is exactly do you expect `vehicle` to be?

Comment: As shown in in the question, I want my final datastructure `v` to be of type `[]vehicle` (or `[]*vehicle`, which would be fine too) where the `v[0]` is a `car` and `v[1]` is a plane.

Comment: @JimB: would you be so kind as un-duplicate this question?  I believe I have clarified sufficiently to demonstrate that it is not "an exact duplicate of" [Unmarshal JSON with unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-unknown-fields).

Comment: I fail to see how this is different than any of the other multitude of times it's been asked. The basic answers are always a combination of the suggestions on the linked duplicate. You can unmarshal into a generic structure and manually copy the fields over, or you can just read the "type" field and unmarhsal the object a second time into a specific type. Whether you implement a json.Unmarshaler, or a function to translate from a `[]json.RawMessage{}` to a `[]vehicle` is up to you, but it's going to be a multi-step process that you need to implement.

Comment: Well, one problem is that I can't define an UnmarshalJSON method on vehicle, because it's an interface.  I could create wrapper struct with a single anonymous vehicle field and define UnmarhsalJSON there (and this works), but then I end up with a []vehicleWrapper instead of []vehicle, which is not quite what I want.

Comment: Also, more particularly: this question is actually a yes/no question, so "No, there is not a way to do this" would be a perfectly reasonable (and useful) answer.  I am perfectly capable of finding work-arounds (indeed I have several); this is a question about whether a particular thing—calling json.Unmarshal on a non-empty interface, or slice thereof, and having it select a concrete type based on the JSON data, by whatever means—is possible.

Comment: No, you can't define a method on `vehicle`, but that's not what you want because you need to make the type decision at a higher level. I took a minute to adapt the answers from the other question to your data structures.

Answer (score 14):

Taking the answers from the similar question: [Unmarshal JSON with unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-unknown-fields), we can construct a few ways to unamrshal this JSON object in a `[]vehicle` data structure.

The "Unmarshal with Manual Handling" version can be done by using a generic `[]map[string]interface{}` data structure, then building the correct `vehicles` from the slice of maps. For brevity, this example does leave out the error checking for missing or incorrectly typed fields which the json package would have done.

https://play.golang.org/p/fAY9JwVp-4

```
func NewVehicle(m map[string]interface{}) vehicle {
    switch m["type"].(string) {
    case "car":
        return NewCar(m)
    case "plane":
        return NewPlane(m)
    }
    return nil
}

func NewCar(m map[string]interface{}) *car {
    return &car{
        Type:  m["type"].(string),
        Color: m["color"].(string),
        HP:    int(m["hp"].(float64)),
        Doors: int(m["doors"].(float64)),
    }
}

func NewPlane(m map[string]interface{}) *plane {
    return &plane{
        Type:    m["type"].(string),
        Color:   m["color"].(string),
        Engines: int(m["engines"].(float64)),
    }
}

func main() {
    var vehicles []vehicle

    objs := []map[string]interface{}{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(js, &objs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, obj := range objs {
        vehicles = append(vehicles, NewVehicle(obj))
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", vehicles)
}
```

We could leverage the json package again to take care of the unmarshaling and type checking of the individual structs by unmarshaling a second time directly into the correct type. This could all be wrapped up into a `json.Unmarshaler` implementation by defining an `UnmarshalJSON` method on the `[]vehicle` type to first split up the JSON objects into raw messages.

https://play.golang.org/p/zQyL0JeB3b

```
type Vehicles []vehicle


func (v *Vehicles) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // this just splits up the JSON array into the raw JSON for each object
    var raw []json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &raw)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, r := range raw {
        // unamrshal into a map to check the "type" field
        var obj map[string]interface{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(r, &obj)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        vehicleType := ""
        if t, ok := obj["type"].(string); ok {
            vehicleType = t
        }

        // unmarshal again into the correct type
        var actual vehicle
        switch vehicleType {
        case "car":
            actual = &car{}
        case "plane":
            actual = &plane{}
        }

        err = json.Unmarshal(r, actual)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *v = append(*v, actual)

    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON decoding and encoding in Go is actually surprisingly well at recognizing fields inside embedded structs. E.g. decoding or encoding the following structure works when there is no overlapping fields between type `A` and type `B`:

```golang
type T struct{
    Type string `json:"type"`
    *A
    *B
}

type A struct{
    Baz int `json:"baz"`
}

type B struct{
    Bar int `json:"bar"`
}
```

Be aware that if both "baz" and "bar" are set in the JSON for the example above, both the `T.A` and `T.B` properties will be set.

If there is overlapping fields between `A` and `B`, or just to be able to better discard invalid combinations of fields and type, you need to implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface. To not have to first decode fields into a map, you can extend the trick of using embedded structs.

```golang
type TypeSwitch struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

type T struct {
    TypeSwitch
    *A
    *B
}

func (t *T) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &t.TypeSwitch); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch t.Type {
    case "a":
        t.A = &A{}
        return json.Unmarshal(data, t.A)
    case "b":
        t.B = &B{}
        return json.Unmarshal(data, t.B)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unrecognized type value %q", t.Type)
    }

}

type A struct {
    Foo string `json:"bar"`
    Baz int    `json:"baz"`
}

type B struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
    Bar int    `json:"bar"`
}
```

For marshaling back, `json.Marshaler` must also be implemented if there is overlapping fields.

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/UHAdxlVdFQQ

Comment: A valid alternative can also be to move the `Type` field to the `A` and `B` structs. Example of that here https://play.golang.org/p/hgTVReePg3W

Answer (score 1):

The two passes approach works fine, but there is also the option of the [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) package, that was created to do exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

I'm using the lib `github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure` together the `encoding/json`.

I first, unmarshal the json to a map, and use `mapstructure` to convert the map to my struct, e.g.:

```golang
type (
  Foo struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
  }
  Bar struct {
    Bar string `json:"bar"`
  }
)

func Load(jsonStr string, makeInstance func(typ string) any) (any, error) {
    // json to map
    m := make(map[string]any)
    e := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &m)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }

    data := makeInstance(m["type"].(string))

    // decoder to copy map values to my struct using json tags
    cfg := &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        Metadata: nil,
        Result:   &data,
        TagName:  "json",
        Squash:   true,
    }
    decoder, e := mapstructure.NewDecoder(cfg)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }
    // copy map to struct
    e = decoder.Decode(m)
    return data, e
}
```

Using:

```golang
f, _ := Load(`{"type": "Foo", "foo": "bar"}`, func(typ string) any {
        switch typ {
        case "Foo":
            return &Foo{}
        }
        return nil
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

If the property is a string you can use .(string) for casting the property because the origin is an interface.
You can use it the next way:
**`v["type"].(string)`**

Comment: You appear to be answering a different question than I asked.  I'm not struggling to *access* the `type` field, but to get `json.Unmarshal` to make  intelligent use of it.