# Unmarshal json into interface with many implementations

Tags: json, go, deserialization, unmarshalling

I am building an event sourcing system with many events.
I need to unmarshal a json object into one of the possible event types.
I know I can do something like:

```
type TypedJson struct {
    Type string
    Data json.RawMessage
}

func SerializeJson(event IEvent) []byte {
    data, _:= json.Marshal(event)
    dataType := reflect.TypeOf(event).String()
    typeName := dataType[strings.LastIndex(dataType, ".")+1:]
    typedThing := TypedJson{typeName, data}
    finalJson, _ := json.Marshal(typedThing)
    return finalJson
}
func Deserialize(jsonData []byte) IEvent {
    var event TypedJson
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &event)
    switch event.Type {
    case "UserCreated":
        var e UserCreated
        json.Unmarshal(event.Data, &e)
        return e
    case "EmailChanged":
        var e EmailChanged
        json.Unmarshal(event.Data, &e)
        return e
    case ...
    }
}
```

But it seems inconvenient when there are many events to consider.
Is there a better approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to have json.Unmarshal() select struct type based on "type" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721732/is-there-a-way-to-have-json-unmarshal-select-struct-type-based-on-type-prope)

Comment: also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453782/unmarshal-dynamic-json-based-on-a-type-key

Comment: Are the repetitive case blocks the inconvenience?  Is the event.Type always an exact match with the type name?

Comment: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure can be convenient when you have to determine the target type from json contents.