# Unmarshal dynamic json content in Go

Tags: json, go, dynamic, struct

I have a dynamic json object which I want to unmarshal in my Go app. The problem is that some parts of the json are dynamically named, so I don't know what to put in the struc type json tags. To illustrate my problem, please see this playground: https://play.golang.org/p/q8J0VVO7uj

As you can see the `s1` can perfectly be unmarshalled, because the struct type indeed has tag `description`. But `s2` cannot be unmarshalled.

So my question is: how can I solve this? Can I make use of interfaces here?

Comment: Do you have set of known keys like `description` or just a description?

Comment: Nope, `description` is just one of many values. No known set unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshal JSON with unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-unknown-fields)

Comment: Thanks, Options are 1) Currently you have inline struct definition instead create individual and handle it with struct composition, at top-level you will end up with two struct, rest would be same 2) Handle it with two fields in the `ChangedMetadata` 3) Use `map[string]interface{}` for `ChangedMetadata`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse/deserlize a dynamic JSON in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserlize-a-dynamic-json-in-golang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map for dynamic keys:

```
type ElvisEvent struct {
    Timestamp int64  `json:"timestamp"`
    Type      string `json:"type"`
    AssetID   string `json:"assetId"`
    Metadata  struct {
    } `json:"metadata"`

    ChangedMetadata map[string]struct {
        OldValue interface{} `json:"oldValue"`
        NewValue interface{} `json:"newValue"`
    } `json:"changedMetadata"`
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/7_9VS_hcfM)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the keys `description` and `otherKey` are not part of a list that I know. They are also "dynamic". So is there a way to get these values as well?

Comment: At any place that is dynamic use interface{} ... You'll pay for it later when you have to type cast to access the data, or you can map[string]interface{}

Comment: @RogierLommers The field ChangedMetadata is map.  Range over the map to find the keys as one would do with any other map.