# Solution for Generic in Go

Tags: json, go

I want to make a useful library for JSON responses. In Java I've this already. I started now new with Go and have no idea how to transform my Java code. I've read that Go doesn't have anything like generics, but how can I solve my problem?

I'm talking about the following part of code:

```
@Data
public class ServiceResult<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private ServiceResultStatus status;
    private String type;
    private T content;
    private String hash;
    private String destination;
    private HashMap<String, Metadata> metadata = new HashMap<>();

...
```

The idea of service-result is to provide an structural pattern for RESTful web services. If you need more information, here is the link to my repo on Github: https://github.com/Viascom/service-result

A service-result looks at the end like this:

```
{
  "status": "successful",
  "type": "ch.viascom.example.models.response.GetTasksResponse",
  "content": [
    {
      "id": "3e99c7fb-0ed7-11e7-a7a5-0050569c3e5a",
      "name": "Example Task"
    }
  ],
  "hash": "7bf9c04d1e9f8fe7995e4b8beeac1a4c830e7ea",
  "destination": "ch.viascom.example.handler.TaskHandler",
  "metadata": {

  }
}
```

Comment: First tip: Don't translate Java (or any other language) to Go. Write new code, using Go idioms.

Comment: @Flimzy in this particular case "go idioms" means "copy-paste"?

Comment: @zerkms: I don't have any idea what you mean. I also don't really know what you're trying to do, since you haven't included any functional code--only data types and definitions. So it's really hard to prescribe a Go idiom to an unknown problem.

Comment: @Flimzy from what I see in the OP's question: they have a service that generates responses that have common metadata fields + typed but different payload (see the `content` field). In JAVA they can easily deserialise it in type safe manner using mechanism of generics. So OP asked how to do that in Go idiomatically. Since the most straightforward solution to copy-paste it for every payload type looks inefficient.

Comment: @zerkms: If that's the case, then it's probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33436730/13860

Comment: @Flimzy The fields are known. The type of payload comes directly in the metadata. See `type` field (plus presumably it is known compile time for every service call). The problem OP observes is that there are different type of responses each of which has the same metadata but different payloads. And they are stuck because Go does not have generics, so it's not immediately obvious how you solve it without copy-pasting the similar but slightly different structure types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the json-mapping directly to the structure definition and use the encoder, decoder to marshal and unmarshal it. It's all built in and easier than in other languages, imho.

```
type ServiceResponse struct {
    Value string`json:"nameInJsonResponse"`
}
```

here is a good example from the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4L2wMVv7tW

For your particular case it should be something like this:

```
type ServiceResult struct {
    Status ServiceResultStatus`json:"status"`
    Type string`json:"type"`
    Hash string`json:"hash"`
    Destination string`json:"destination"`
    Metadata map[string]Metadata metadata`json:"metadata"`
}

type ExplizitServiceResult struct {
    ServiceResult
    Content SomeStruct`json:"content"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FFfiq6LxVt

If you don't want to derive every user struct from the ServiceResult you can define the content as `interface{}` so every struct can be inserted. I've updated my example for this. Maybe this is the easiest solution to your problem.
https://play.golang.org/p/LNgreqrnnw

Comment: So how would you do that for the very structure OP provided? Your reference on playground is straightforward and not relevant to the problem OP observes.

Comment: Now it's much better indeed.

Comment: Thanks. Also I was curious and tried it in the playground. And it works as intended. Link's added.

Comment: My main question is how I can extract this as library. The content should be provided by the consumer of the library and not directly in the code. I wanna provide this like a framework. The java generic part should be variable for each project where service-result is used.

Comment: You can add some functions to the `ServiceResult` struct and use them in all derived structs. 
I also added an alternative solution to my answer which is the closest to your Java implementation I think.

Comment: @NikolaStankovic you cannot have it so generic as java provides. There simply is no mechanism in golang for that.