# identify the type of an object dynamically while reading json data

Tags: json, go, reflection

Quite new to go, sorry if this question sounds obvious.

I would like to use reflection in order to identify the type of an object while reading a json file.

The use case (please see the code below) is the following: I have two structs BoyGift and GirlGift that contain different fields. I have also a Boolean indicator IsBoy that is true if the recipient of the giftis a boy, false otherwise.

The type that encapsulates this behavior is the type Gift:

```
//Gift type
type Gift struct {
    IsBoy   bool     `json:"isBoy"`
    Payload ??? `json:"payload"`
}
```

that holds the data. How can I define that type in order the json unmarshal to convert dynamically to the correct type? The "json schema" in this case defines that a Gift should be either a BoyGift or a GirlGift. Is it possible to do this via reflection? How?

Doing unmarshal twice would be great, if the Boolean info is known

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

//BoyGift type
type BoyGift struct {
    Cars  uint32 `json:"cars"`
    Balls uint32 `json:"balls"`
}

//GirlGift type
type GirlGift struct {
    Dolls uint32 `json:"dolls"`
    Lego  uint32 `json:"lego"`
}

//Gift type
type Gift struct {
    IsBoy   bool     `json:"isBoy"`
    Payload GirlGift `json:"payload"`
}

func main() {

    b := []byte(`{
        "isBoy": true,
        "payload": {
          "cars": 1,
          "balls": 2
        }
      }`)

    var g Gift
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &g)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(g)
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to create dynamic type for a struct field. If you are not sure you can use interface and then assign it to the structs given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshal JSON with unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-unknown-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) to dynamically unmarshal your data.

You can define Gift's Payliad as `json.RawMessage` and then delay unmarshaling until you know the value of `IsBoy`. Below you can find a basic example of how to do it.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

//BoyGift type
type BoyGift struct {
    Cars  uint32 `json:"cars"`
    Balls uint32 `json:"balls"`
}

//GirlGift type
type GirlGift struct {
    Dolls uint32 `json:"dolls"`
    Lego  uint32 `json:"lego"`
}

//Gift type
type Gift struct {
    IsBoy   bool            `json:"isBoy"`
    Payload json.RawMessage `json:"payload"`
}

func main() {

    b1 := []byte(`{
        "isBoy": true,
        "payload": {
          "cars": 1,
          "balls": 2
        }
      }`)

    b2 := []byte(`{
        "isBoy": false,
        "payload": {
          "dolls": 3,
          "lego": 4
        }
      }`)

    for _, b := range [][]byte{b1, b2} {
        var g Gift

        err := json.Unmarshal(b, &g)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        if g.IsBoy {
            var boyGift BoyGift
            err := json.Unmarshal(g.Payload, &boyGift)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(boyGift)

        } else {
            var girlGift GirlGift
            err := json.Unmarshal(g.Payload, &girlGift)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(girlGift)

        }
    }

}
```

If you want to use `Payload` as an `interface{}` (which can be `BoyGift` or `GirlGift`), you could create additional helper struct for unmarshalling. Check extended example in Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/q1Hn45bgjsc