# How to handle missing fields in a JSON response dynamically in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm working on a Go wrapper for an API and I noticed that two of the JSON fields stay empty when they don't have any data.
Basically the API returns a set of information on a given url, and if it was visited at least once, everything is okay and I get a full json that I then Unmarshal into a struct:

```
{
   "stats":{
      "status":1,
      "date":"09.07.2019",
      "title":"Test",
      "devices":{
         "dev":[
            {
               "tag":"Desktop"
            }
         ],
         "sys":[
            {
               "tag":"GNU/Linux "
            },
            {
               "tag":"Windows 10"
            }
         ],
         "bro":[
            {
               "tag":"Firefox 67.0"
            },
            {
               "tag":"Chrome 62.0"
            }
         ]
      },
      "refs":[
         {
            "link":"www.google.com"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is the struct I'm using:

```
type Stats struct {
    Stats struct {
        Status  int    `json:"status"`
        Date    string `json:"date"`
        Title   string `json:"title"`
        Devices struct {
            Dev []struct {
                Tag string `json:"tag"`
            } `json:"dev"`
            Sys []struct {
                Tag string `json:"tag"`
            } `json:"sys"`
            Bro []struct {
                Tag string `json:"tag"`
            } `json:"bro"`
        } `json:"devices"`
        Refs []struct {
            Link string `json:"link"`
        } `json:"refs"`
    } `json:"stats"`
}
```

When a new url is given, then things become a little bit weird:

```
{
  "stats": {
    "status": 1,
    "date": "09.07.2019",
    "title": "Test2",
    "devices": [

    ],
    "refs": [

    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the fields "dev", "sys" and "bro" just disappear because they're not used and when I try to Unmarshal the JSON into the same struct I get `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Stats.device of type [...]`
I tried to use two different structs to handle both the responses but I'm sure that there's a way to handle them gracefully with just one.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Missing fields are never a problem when unmarshaling JSON. Go just skips them. But your two structs are actually different. That's not your problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with complete JSON for the two different payloads you need to decode?

Comment: @Flimzy that's where the issues start, because the two JSONs come from the same source, what do you mean by complete JSON?

Comment: I don't think there's a particularly good way to handle something like this. You have one field (`devices`) that can have two different types, object or array. You can define it as type `interface{}` in your struct and see whether it's a slice or a map. I think the two possible types you would see are `[]interface{}` and `map[string]interface{}`. I don't know that that's any better than what you're doing now (two different struct definitions).

Comment: I mean *complete JSON*. The JSON in your question is incomplete. It appears to have missing bits.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33436730/13860  The key is to unmarshal twice. You can encapsulate that in a custom unmarshaler, though.

Comment: Ok guys, I finally managed to kind of make it work with just one struct, using ```interface{}``` for Device and Refs, but it's ugly and I constantly have to use a JSON conversion in between to force the use of Stats.Device instead of map[string]interface{}. @Flimzy the JSON isn't incomplete, is just wrong from the server side, because they send "devices" and "refs" as an object first and as an empty array later, depending on the link I give them. I contacted their support and they'll probably resolve the issue. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: I'm glad you got something working. But please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead, provide an answer below.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, I deleted the edit and posted a new answer, I'm new here and it's my first question. Thank you very much

Comment: Well done. Thanks for providing your own answer!  You can also accept your own answer (some times after a delay) to indicate that it was the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work with an ugly workaround.
I changed my struct to

```
type Stats struct {
    Status     int         `json:"status"`
    Date       string      `json:"date"`
    Title      string      `json:"title"`
    Devices    interface{} `json:"devices"`
    Refs       interface{} `json:"refs"`
}
```

Then I can finally Unmarshal the JSON in both cases, but I get a `map[string]interface{}` when an object is passed and an empty `interface{}` when an empty array is passed. In order to fix this inconsistency, I simply check for the data type and force the use of a JSON intermediate conversion in order to unpack the `map[string]interface{}` value inside a custom `Devices` struct:

```
// Devices contains devices information
type Devices struct {
    Dev []struct {
        Tag    string `json:"tag"`
        Clicks string `json:"clicks"`
    } `json:"dev"`
    Sys []struct {
        Tag    string `json:"tag"`
        Clicks string `json:"clicks"`
    } `json:"sys"`
    Bro []struct {
        Tag    string `json:"tag"`
        Clicks string `json:"clicks"`
    } `json:"bro"`
}
```

The algorithms I use are the following:

```
//ForceDevicesToRightType uses a json conversion as intermediary for filling the Stats.Devices
// struct with map[string]interface{} values
func ForceDevicesToRightType(dev interface{}) (Devices, error) {
    temp, err := json.Marshal(dev)
    if err != nil {
        return Devices{}, err
    }
    // Use a temporary variable of the right type
    var devices Devices
    err = json.Unmarshal(temp, &devices)
    if err != nil {
        return Devices{}, err
    }

    return devices, nil
}
```

```
// ForceRefsToRightType uses a json conversion as intermediary for filling the Stats.Refs
// struct with map[string]interface{} values
func ForceRefsToRightType(refs interface{}) (Refs, error) {
    temp, err := json.Marshal(refs)
    if err != nil {
        return Refs{}, err
    }
    // Use a temporary variable of the right type
    var references Refs
    err = json.Unmarshal(temp, &references)
    if err != nil {
        return Refs{}, err
    }

    return references, nil
}
```

Since the compiler knows that both Devices and Refs fields are `interface{}` I cannot simply access any methods after the conversion, so I simply make a cast of the right type and everything works fine.
For example, if I wanted to access the Dev sub-struct, this is the proper way:

```
y, _ := GetStats()
fmt.Println(y.Devices.(Devices).Dev)
```

It's ugly, but it works.

**Thank you very much for your help, I hope that this method will save you an headache!**