# Empty struct on Unmarshall JSON with unknown key

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I'm getting from and API a JSON like the following:

```
{
  "unknownkey" : {
    "sum" : 7030.76636,
    "low" : 6787.05692,
    "avg" : 0.00014
  }
}
```

First key is unknown - it changes, but the struct inside holds always the same keys.
Following the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-some-known-and-some-unknown-field-names) I created the these `structs`:

```
type Order struct {
  Result Result `json:"-"`
}

type Result struct {
  Sum        float64    `json:"sum"`
  Low        float64    `json:"low"`
  Avg        float64      `json:"avg"`
}
```

Which I try to unmarshall it like this:

```
var order Order
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &order)
```

but I just get an empty struct:

```
{Result:{Sum:0 Low:0 Avg:0}}
```

Comment: You didn't follow that discussion properly. `json:"-"` means "don't unmarshal JSON here at all".

Comment: instead of struct use a map `map[string]Result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a map with value type being `Result` or `*Result`:

```
var wrapper map[string]Result

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &wrapper); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", wrapper)
```

This will result in:

```
map[unknownkey:{Sum:7030.76636 Low:6787.05692 Avg:0.00014}]
```

If you need the `Result` object, range over the map:

```
for key, result := range wrapper {
    fmt.Printf("Key: %q, Result: %+v", key, result)
}
```

This outputs:

```
Key: "unknownkey", Result: {Sum:7030.76636 Low:6787.05692 Avg:0.00014}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pBUlVwYOsaW).

Comment: If we want to take unknownkey to any property for struct, is it possible? I mean if i want that output `{Key:"unknownkey", Sum:43242, Avg:54354...}` without using map iteration. Is it possible with type decleration?

Comment: @yabadabaduhast For that output, add `Key` to `Result`.

Comment: I asked with example, it is too long to add as comment so i added to gist.

https://gist.github.com/xephtar/8ff653edb6306e1218dc8389279bb05b

Comment: Post a new question as a new question, not as a comment on another answer.

Comment: Okay, you are right!