# Unmarshal dynamic JSON Golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to Unmarshal an API response which has a dynamic field :

API response :

```
[
{
    "id": "3412345678",
    "userName": "ichigo",
    "sub": "ichi",
    "opnum": "324.45",
    "applyRoot": [
        "Paradise"
    ],
    "prm": [],
    "requestNumber": "",
    "individualStatus": {
        "app-first": {
            "is_running": false,
            "version-stats": [
                {
                    "digit": "1.23.341",
                    "expected_num": 0,
                    "current_num": 0,
                    "type": "queued"
                }
            ],
            "_data": {
                "digit": "12-rated",
                "expected_num": 0,
                "current_num": 0
            },
            "status": "timeout",
            "count": 1
        },
        "app-second": {
            "is_running": false,
            "version-stats": [
                {
                    "digit": "1.23.341",
                    "expected_num": 0,
                    "current_num": 0,
                    "type": "queued"
                }
            ],
            "_data": {
                "digit": "12-rated",
                "expected_num": 0,
                "current_num": 0
            },
            "status": "timeout",
            "count": 1
        }

    }
}
]
```

The model i tried for Unmarshalling the json is :

```
type AutoGenerated []struct {
ID               string        `json:"id"`
UserName         string        `json:"userName"`
Sub              string        `json:"sub"`
Opnum            string        `json:"opnum"`
ApplyRoot        []string      `json:"applyRoot"`
Prm              []interface{} `json:"prm"`
RequestNumber    string        `json:"requestNumber"`
IndividualStatus map[string]interface{} `json:"individualAppStatus"`
```

}

What would be the correct method to Unmarshal the Json and access the IndividualStatus values.

I tried following [Unmarshal JSON with some known, and some unknown field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436730/unmarshal-json-with-some-known-and-some-unknown-field-names) , in this case i have to delete the values as mentioned (the values i have to delete is large). Pls let me know the best way.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the IndividualStatus values have a common structure.  Declare the field as `IndividualStatus map[string]T`  where T is a Go type that matches the common structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a defined structure for the `IndividualStatus` and use as following.

```golang
type IndividualStatus struct {
    IsRunning    bool `json:"is_running"`
    VersionStats []struct {
        Digit       string `json:"digit"`
        ExpectedNum int    `json:"expected_num"`
        CurrentNum  int    `json:"current_num"`
        Type        string `json:"type"`
    } `json:"version-stats"`
    Data struct {
        Digit       string `json:"digit"`
        ExpectedNum int    `json:"expected_num"`
        CurrentNum  int    `json:"current_num"`
    } `json:"_data"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
    Count  int    `json:"count"`
}

type APIResponse []struct {
    IndividualStatus map[string]IndividualStatus
}
```

You can unmarshal your `json` response to this `APIResponse` and access each one of `IndividualStatus` field.

You can further modularize internal fields in `IndividualStatus` struct if you want.